# Configure Docker to use SSL for a private registry on Windows 10?

Tags: docker, windows, powershell

Trying to use a customer registry from a Windows 10 system - a native Docker client in PowerShell.

```
PS > docker --version

Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1287
PS > docker pull REPO_URL/foo-bar:0.1

Error response from daemon: get https://REPO_URL/v2/: x509: 
certificate signed by unknown authority.
```

Importing the authority certificate to local user store via Windows tooling works for itself but has no effect here.

Comment: You may wish to follow the steps on this [Issue comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21189#issuecomment-288694477)

Comment: works! now, shall I delete this question?

Comment: You may wish to self answer with the steps you did to make it work and maybe extend a little about how it differs on win10 than previous versions ?

Comment: exactly those steps worked, with the only difference I did a right-click import and then had to copy over the certificate. Is that a valuable answer here?

Comment: I'd say yes, working with certificates is always a pain and it seems the official doc doesn't cover this point properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/faqs/#are-symlinks-supported) says:

> Docker recognizes certs stored under **Trust Root Certification
>   Authorities** or **Intermediate Certification Authorities**.

That is, you can proceed [as the following](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21189#issuecomment-288694477):

- Start > "Manage Computer Certificates" (also available in the control
  panel)
- Right-click on "Trusted Root Certification Authoritites" >
  "All tasks" > "Import"
- Browse to the crt file and then keep pressing "Next" to complete the wizard
- Restart Docker for Windows

In my case, the catch was that I imported the certificate via the context menu, and therefore it went to another folder where Docker could not access it. The certificate store behaves however very much like the normal Windows Explorer tree folder, so I had just to copy the certificate over to the supported category, and after Docker restart it worked.

Comment: I had 5 certificate files (.crt): root, server, server-chained, client, client-chained. First 3 is used in private docker-registry accessible via UI through SSL. Now which (out of 5) to be imported into windows ??